# weird problem：SHFILEOPSTRUCT.pFrom changes after being assigned

Tags: c++, windows

I am using visual studio on windows10 using C++,when I code like below.

And in debug mode, after fop.fFrom was assigned as "C:\Users\C++.docx", weird thing happend, after
cst = vrdir2.c_str() + '\0', the fop.fFrom changes into "D:\vr". I am quite confused about why would this happen.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<io.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include<direct.h>
#include<atlstr.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "shell32.lib")
using namespace std;
long long LAST_TIME_STAMP;
int main() {
    string vrdir1 = "C:\\Users\\C++.docx";//version record dir
    string vrdir2 = "D:\\vr";
    SHFILEOPSTRUCT fop;//shell file opration struct
    ZeroMemory(&fop, sizeof fop);
    fop.wFunc = FO_COPY;
    CString cst = vrdir1.c_str() + '\0';
    cst.AppendChar(0);
    fop.pFrom = cst;
    cst = vrdir2.c_str() + '\0';
    cst.AppendChar(0);
    fop.pTo = cst;
}
```

Comment: pFrom is just a pointer, not a smart type like CString.  fop.pFrom = cst; assigns a *temporary* to pFrom, it is only valid as long as cst stays in scope.  But the code then changes cst, also changing what the temporary points to.  Using another CString to initialize pTo would be a basic workaround.

Answer (score 0):

`pFrom` is a pointer. It points to `cst`'s memory. If you change `cst` it changes `pFrom` as well. It is similar to this scenario:

```
int x = 5;
int *px = &x;
x = 10;
```

`px` points to `x`'s memory. If you change `x` this change is visible through `px` as well.

In your example, you could simply do this:

```
string vrdir1 = "C:\\Users\\C++.docx";//version record dir
string vrdir2 = "D:\\vr";
SHFILEOPSTRUCT fop;//shell file opration struct
ZeroMemory(&fop, sizeof fop);
fop.wFunc = FO_COPY;
fop.pFrom = vrdir1.c_str();
fop.pTo = vrdir2.c_str();
```

without using `CString`.

As an advice, please don't mix the different string types. Choose one, and stick to that.

Comment: Thanks friend, I didn't notice that fop.pfrom is a pointer. Good Job!